# Реализация CRC-8. За что отвечает параметр init?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, hashcode, crc

Кодирую программку для CRC разных стандартов. (побитовая обработка)
Застрял на параметре init. При init = 0x00 работает правильно, причем не только для CRC-8...Но как только меняешь init, то значения выдает не правильно. В чем проблема ? init же только должен менять начальное значение регистра ?

CRC-8 / init = 0x00, poly = 0x07 - работает нормально
CRC-8 CDMA / init = 0xFF, poly = 0x9b - уже нет

CRC-8:

```
    int CRC8() {
    dynamic_bitset<> regix = MyCRC::GetRegixAsBits(0x00, 8); // init = 0x00
    dynamic_bitset<> mess = MyCRC::GetIntAsBitset(0x41, 8);  // mess = 0x41
    dynamic_bitset<> poly = MyCRC::GetPolyAsBitset(8, 0x07); // poly = 0x07

    cout << regix << endl; // 0000 0000 == 0x00
    cout << mess << endl;  // 0100 0001 0000 0000 == 0x41 + 8 нулей
    cout << poly << endl;  // 0000 0111 == 0x07

    while (mess.size() > 0) {
        if (regix[7] == 0) {
            regix = regix << 1;
            regix[0] = mess[mess.size() - 1];
        }
        else {
            regix = regix << 1;
            regix[0] = mess[mess.size() - 1];
            regix = regix ^ poly;
        }
        mess.pop_back();
    }

    cout << hex << regix.to_ulong() << endl; // 1100 0000 = 0xC0 | 0xC0 (crccalc.com) OK

    return regix.to_ulong();
}
```

CRC-8 CDMA:

```
int CRC8_CDMA() {
    dynamic_bitset<> regix = MyCRC::GetRegixAsBits(0xFF, 8); // init = 0xFF
    dynamic_bitset<> mess = MyCRC::GetIntAsBitset(0x41, 8);  // mess = 0x41
    dynamic_bitset<> poly = MyCRC::GetPolyAsBitset(8, 0x9b); // poly = 0x9b

    cout << regix << endl; // 1111 1111 == 0xFF
    cout << mess << endl;  // 0100 0001 0000 0000 == 0x41 + 8 нулей
    cout << poly << endl;  // 1001 1011 == 0x9b

    while (mess.size() > 0) {
        if (regix[7] == 0) {
            regix = regix << 1;
            regix[0] = mess[mess.size() - 1];
        }
        else {
            regix = regix << 1;
            regix[0] = mess[mess.size() - 1];
            regix = regix ^ poly;
        }
        mess.pop_back();
    }

    cout << hex << regix.to_ulong() << endl; // 1110 0010 = 0xE2 | 0x28 (crccalc.com) FALSE

    return regix.to_ulong();
}
```

Comment: Какой-то странный вопрос... Перефразируя - у меня есть функция f(x,y), но почему-то, когда я меняю x, функция возвращает другое значение... Так я вас понял?

Comment: @Harry в попытках написать кратко и четко не всегда добиваешься успеха...добавил в комментариях кода откуда проверяю значения